# Maximum allowed memory for Tomcat 6.0 and Tomcat 7.0

Tags: tomcat

Currently I am using Tomcat 5.5 but it has a memory limit of 2 GB max. As my application requires more memory, I am thinking of upgrading my tomcat installation.

Can any one tell me the maximum allowed memory for Tomcat 6.0 and Tomcat 7.0? Is there any other benefits of using Tomcat 6.0 or Tomcat 7.0 over Tomcat 5.5?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, to increase memory beyond 2GB you have to run Tomcat with 64 bit support.  In our case we are using 64 bit OS and Apache Tomcat/7.0.14 which is currently using 
Max memory: 2840.00 MB as shown on Tomcat server status page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please tell me if i run Tomcat 5.5 in 64-bit machine then how much memory i can get? And if i use Tomcat 6.0 then how much memory i can use? And what is the advantage you get while using Tomcat/7.0.14 over Tomcat 5.5?

Comment: Memory limitation is not imposed by Tomcat . It is OS and JVM specific. With 64 bit OS and JVM, limit is infinite.